# Remote debugging Windows 2000 with VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, remote-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to target .NET 2 so a portion of our software can run on Windows 2000.  I need to remote debug a process and the remote debugger in VS 2008 will not install on Windows 2000.  I have installed the VS 2005 version of the debugger and can make a connection to it from VS 2008, but it gives an error "The remote debugger is not an acceptable version."  Is there any way to make this work...maybe by having VS 2008 use the old version of the remote debugger to connect (given all code is .net 2)?  I'd really rather not make a VS2005 version of the solution given it has many, many projects, and many, many files.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft is dropping Windows 2000 this July.  Are you sure this is worth the effort?

Comment: It is absolutely not worth it, but its a customer requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply copy the remote debugger exe and associated files to the machine you need to debug. No need to actually run the installer. You can find the files at a path similar to:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger{version}

It may be that the 2008 version is simply incompatible with Windows 2000, but at the very least copying the files will get you the correct bits on the machine to try.